# Counting by month unique users who have paid in the last 12 months, grouping them by month

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I'd like to create a code that counts month by month unique users who have paid in the last 12 months.

| Month | unique_customers |
| --- | --- |
| Oct-23 | 3000 |
| Sep-23 | 2000 |
| Aug-23 | 1000 |

Where the range for Oct-23 is all customers who paid between oct-23 and nov-22 and so on

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created) AS month,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customerId) AS unique_customers
FROM payments
WHERE 
  created >= DATE_SUB(created, INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM created)
ORDER BY month
```

And in in this case calculates the customers without the window of 12 month

Also I tried with OVER but my version doesn't support OVER with DISTINCT

Thanks